# cmd echo save %USERPROFILE% as string to a text

Tags: batch-file, cmd, user-profile, regedit

I want to save %USERPROFILE% as a string read from regedit to a text file,but the cmd changes to "C:\Users\Administrator",does anybody know how to fix it?
What I want is saves like this :

"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft" in a.txt

not

"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft" in a.txt

The Code:

```
echo %USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft >> c:\a.txt
```

Comment: `%` is a deference operator for **variable** so you have to prevent the **%** it self. Try this: "%% you variable %%" . may be works.

Comment: Do not include solutions in questions; provide your own answer instead!

Comment: Also as you didn't answer the question referencing regedit, I can only assume you're writing the output for use as input to a .reg file. Are you aware that if you use reg.exe you can add the registry entry directly with the normal path, _there will be no need to double up the back slashes for instance_.

Answer (score 1):

You double up the percents to prevent the expansion:

`Echo="%%LocalAppData%%\Microsoft">a.txt`

Also, notice the changed environment variable, which defines the location you were looking for.

Comment: I just want to get the regedit string value and then save it to a text via cmd,and want it keep as the same as regedit string.

Comment: There was nothing at all about regedit in your question. Please update your original question with the real task and details, so that we can provide a more specific response.

Answer (score 1):

### Update Solution

Finally,I find a solution myself,thanks for all kindly help,the codes here:

```
Set _a=%
Set _b=USERPROFILE
Echo %_a%%_b%%_a%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft >> c:\a.txt
```

There will be works correctly in any machine,hope this can help someone who needed it like me.

Answer (score 0):

In general, precede an awkward character like `&<>` etc., with a caret `^` to use `echo` to show it.

Naturally, `%` is the exception. You need to escape `%` with `%` thus : `%%`

Comment: Thanks for help,you meant:echo %%USERPROFILE%%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft >> c:\a.txt?Am I wrong?the output text is %C:\Users\Administrator%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft

Comment: `echo %%USERPROFILE%%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft >> c:\a.txt`  produces `%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft` in the file on my machine...